# how to export/move my Azure Machine Learning Workspace to different subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using azure machine learning services. I have created an experiment and deployed as a webservice on Azure Machine Learning Workspace.

My problem Is my subscription has expired and now I want to export/move my Azure Machine Learning Workspace to different subscription so I can reuse its all content(model, experiment etc.) without losing.

How can I save my all important work and  export or move Azure Machine Learning Workspace with all working functionalities in different subscription?

Thank you

Regards,

Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

The following document demonstrates how to [migrate Azure resources across subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription). You should be able to migrate your workspace as indicated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftmachinelearning).

As highlighted in the document above, if the tenant IDs for the source and destination subscriptions aren't the same, use the following methods to reconcile the tenant IDs:

- [Transfer ownership of an Azure subscription to another account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer)
- [How to associate or add an Azure subscription to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory)

The source and destination subscriptions must be active. If you have trouble enabling an account that has been disabled, create an [Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). Select **Subscription Management** for the issue type.

Answer (score 0):

This document says that moving an AML workspace is currently not supported:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-workspace

In this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftmachinelearning) referenced in a previous answer, .MachineLearning refers to the classic ML studio. You should be looking for .MachineLearningServices which refers to the new AML studio which clearly states that moving between resource groups or subscriptions is not supported.

I'm looking to do this myself but I haven't found a complete solution.